# Json string deserialization C#

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

[I have this json](http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198297267814/inventory/json/730/2/?trading=1)
and i want to deserialize it so I can get each object's value for example:

```
"icon_url": "-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpouLWzKjhzw8zFdC5K092kl5SClMj3PLXFhGpC_Pp8j-3I4IG7i1Hn_UI-Nmj3ItDGe1BoN1mCr1G4xL_vhMS8tcmcn3JhuihwsHvbzQv3309k3tBw8A",
```

The problem is I can make the class(es) that I need so I can deserialize the json because the json string has nested objects.

Comment: You can deserialize nested objects with the right classes. What have you tried?

Comment: [My Classes](http://pastebin.com/8WXZihKr) i use the JsonInv to deserialze

Comment: Do you just want all the `icon_url` data and don't care about what objects they belong to?

Comment: What's the problem again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) to help me generate classes. After some merging and cleaning up, this is what I got:

```
public class InventoryItem
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string classid { get; set; }
    public string instanceid { get; set; }
    public string amount { get; set; }
    public int pos { get; set; }
}

public class AppData
{
    public string def_index { get; set; }
    public int? is_itemset_name { get; set; }
    public int? limited { get; set; }
}

public class Description
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
    public string color { get; set; }
    public AppData app_data { get; set; }
}

public class Action
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string link { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public string internal_name { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
    public string category_name { get; set; }
    public string color { get; set; }
}

public class RgDescription
{
    public string appid { get; set; }
    public string classid { get; set; }
    public string instanceid { get; set; }
    public string icon_url { get; set; }
    public string icon_url_large { get; set; }
    public string icon_drag_url { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string market_hash_name { get; set; }
    public string market_name { get; set; }
    public string name_color { get; set; }
    public string background_color { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public int tradable { get; set; }
    public int marketable { get; set; }
    public int commodity { get; set; }
    public string market_tradable_restriction { get; set; }
    public List<Description> descriptions { get; set; }
    public List<Action> actions { get; set; }
    public List<Action> market_actions { get; set; }
    public List<Tag> tags { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, InventoryItem> rgInventory { get; set; }
    public List<object> rgCurrency { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, RgDescription> rgDescriptions { get; set; }
    public bool more { get; set; }
    public bool more_start { get; set; }
}
```

These appear to work correctly, you can deserialize and serialize with code like this:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(oldString);
Console.WriteLine(obj.rgDescriptions["310776560_302028390"].icon_url); // e.g.
var newString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj,
     new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });
// null value handling is optional, the above makes it a little more like the source string
```

Comment: Thank u very much u gave a clue so i could find the solution because ["310776560_302028390"] this can change if i give the item(["310776560_302028390"] is a unique item in steam) also i had to generate the "310776560_302028390" from  this `string item = obj.rgInventory["6596605087"].classid + "_" + obj.rgInventory["6596605087"].instanceid;` anyway thank u very much!

Comment: Haha... json2csharp... did you have to take out all of the "public class _invalid_type..."